# How to add ADMOB banner to Unity?

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, admob

i tried to use the guide given with the official plugin but i either fail to understand how to add the banner ad or the instructions are too vague can someone enlighten me a little better how to add the banner to one of the scenes in my 2D game?

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity

Comment: thanks for the help by downvoting my question for no reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new script in c# and include following code.

> using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

Now you have to create a new adbanner and initialized it. so in the start function simply add the following code.

> // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen. BannerView
>   bannerView = new BannerView(
>           "YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top); // Create an empty ad request. AdRequest request = new
>   AdRequest.Builder().Build(); // Load the banner with the request.
>   bannerView.LoadAd(request);

See the full tutorial from http://blog.qrallrounder.com/?p=140